# calculate timediff in sec between two rows

Tags: mysql, mariadb

MariaDB 10.3.36 
i need to calculate the timediff in sec between the date row and 
create a new column like diff_sec

[image]

Comment: Please not post data as images. Use text or online services such https://sqlize.online

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id,date,section, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,date,
                  lag(date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date)) as diff_sec 
FROM garagedoor;
```

This works for me. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

(MySQL Code):

```
SELECT id,date,section,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,date,
LAG(date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date)) as diff_sec 
FROM difference;
```

If we run the code,

[image: Updated Solution]

Comment: between id 2 and 3 is the difference
 46s, but get a value of 704

Comment: @Quito96 Difference is based on grouping by section. Difference is calculated only for similar section id's. I am sorry if I misunderstood your demand.